# xslt 1.0 add new elements

Tags: xml, xslt

Below is the input xml:

```
<car>
  <colors>R+G+B</colors>
</car>
```

I would like to change it to:

```
<car>
  <colors>R</colors>
  <colors>G</colors>
  <colors>B</colors>
</car>
```

The value of the original colors element could be any combination of R, G and B. My strategy is to add a new  element per each color value after the first  node.

```
<xsl:template match="node()|@*">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="/ImageProductOrder/color">
 //insert another color element here 
</xsl:template>
```

I am not sure how to actually implement this via XSLT. Or would there be another strategy to get this to work?

Comment: This is for XSLT 1.0

Comment: "*could be any combination of R, G and B.*" Are all the possible values R, G, and B known in advance? -- "*This is for XSLT 1.0*" Which XSLT 1.0 processor in particular?

Comment: Yes the values are just all combinations of R, G and B

Answer (score 1):

> the values are just all combinations of R, G and B

Well, then you could just do:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="colors">
    <xsl:if test="contains(., 'R')">
        <colors>R</colors>
    </xsl:if>
    <xsl:if test="contains(., 'B')">
        <colors>B</colors>
    </xsl:if>
    <xsl:if test="contains(., 'G')">
        <colors>G</colors>
    </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 0):

A more generic approach is to use a recursive template to split on the (configurable) delimiter:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="colors">
        <xsl:call-template name="make-color">
            <xsl:with-param name="val" select="."/>
        </xsl:call-template> 
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template name="make-color">
        <xsl:param name="val"/>
        <xsl:param name="delim" select="'+'"/>
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="contains($val, $delim)">
                <color><xsl:value-of select="substring-before($val, $delim)"/></color>
                <xsl:call-template name="make-color">
                    <xsl:with-param name="val" select="substring-after($val, $delim)"/>
                    <xsl:with-param name="delim" select="$delim"/>
                </xsl:call-template>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
                <color><xsl:value-of select="$val"/></color>
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```